# Thumbnail-like behavior using target attribute of image directive

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I use Sphinx to generate some docs. I have a reStructuredText document and I'd like to put an image into it. The case is that the image should be clickable so that after a user clicks the image then they should be shown this image in full size. I use the image directive and its target option like this:

```
.. image:: /images/some_image.png
   :alt: Image descripion
   :align: center
   :target: `big_some_image`_

.. _big_some_image: /images/some_image.png
```

The problem is that in the rendered page I get:

```
<a href="/images/some_image.png"><img src="../../../_images/some_image.png"></a>
```

So there is correct `src` from the image directive but an incorrect `href` attribute from the hyperlink.

Questions:

- is there any way to generate links in the way that image directive does it? I mean relative to the document.
- is there any other (built in) way to have "thumbnail-> click -> big image" behaviour?

Answer (score 11):

Simply use the scale option:

```
.. image:: large_image.png
    :scale: 20%
```

When the scaled image is clicked on, the full image loads in its own window. So this doesn't increase the image size on the page, but that would be messy anyway.

Comment: While this works, it means you don't get automatic scale-to-fit *(with sphinx 1.3 and RTD theme at least)*

Comment: Yeah, this squishes my image horizontally.  Edit: found this css works around it: `img {
    height: auto !important;
}`

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `image` directive from within Sphinx, Sphinx does some special handling to find the image file and copy it into your project (like your `_images` directory), and then renders the HTML to point to that place.

But the `target` option just takes a URL as a parameter.  It knows nothing about your Sphinx project, or how your images are laid out, and does not attempt to guess.

If you want to have it point to a larger version of the same file, you will likely need to do some manual steps (like maybe copying the file to a specific location), or maybe provide a relative URL to the large file, rather than the absolute URL you have in your example.

If you want to go a completely different way, you could also try overriding and modifying the HTML templates for your project to add some JavaScript to get the click-to-larger-image effect you want.

Comment: Is there really no other way? It's the kind of functionality one could expect to be supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a Sphinx extension that does this now, and quite nicely at that, [sphinxcontrib-fancybox 0.3.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-fancybox/). Install with `pip`, add it to your extensions in conf.py, and use the `fancybox` directive:

```
.. fancybox:: images/image.png
```

Comment: Just tried it. It's still kind of rough around the edges.  Caption only shows on full size image which is a deal breaker for me unfortunately. I need it to do the opposite.  Show the caption only on the thumbnail.

Comment: What I am doing for now is setting a width/height for my thumbnail size.  Then when I click on the image it sends the browser to the image url.  It's the same as using `scale`.  If I can get the browser to open a new window/tab instead I could live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Relative links seem to work.  For the *Mapserver* docs setup, if an image is placed in the `images` directory, a relative link like in the following code works in my local build.  Here is an example using *figure* (the underscore ("_") before "images" in the *target* link is necessary):

```
.. figure:: ../../images/carto-elements.png
  :height: 400
  :width: 600
  :align: center
  :target: ../../_images/symcon-overlay.png
```